# How to create similar animation from Google?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

Found [this site](https://get.google.com/spaces/) today created by Google, I really liked the animation while scrolling this page, but I can't understand how they created this animation ?

It would be great if someone can provide any good artice, course, book about this sort of animation.

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the site is using the [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) framework along with an animation tool called [TweenLite](https://greensock.com/tweenlite) by GreenSock along with their [TimelineMax](https://greensock.com/timelinemax) extension

> **TweenLite** is an extremely fast, lightweight, and flexible animation tool that serves as the foundation of the GreenSock Animation Platform (GSAP). A TweenLite instance handles tweening one or more properties of any object (or array of objects) over time. TweenLite can be used on its own to accomplish most animation chores with minimal file size or it can be used in conjunction with advanced sequencing tools like TimelineLite or TimelineMax to make complex tasks much simpler.

**Source:** [GreenSock](https://greensock.com/)